# Что именно произойдет при арифметическом переполнении?

Tags: bash, cmd

В cmd есть ограничение на хранение целочисленного типа, оно, вроде бы, не превышает 2^16, но что произойдет, если будет вот такой цикл:
for ((a=1; a<=$amount ; a++))
и значение amount превысит допустимый размер?

Comment: А почему бы вам это не проверить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

максимальное целое, с которым программа *bash* способна производить вычисления, теоретически, может варьироваться в зависимости и от реализации этой программы, и от используемой операционной системы, и от архитектуры процессора.

в [реализации *bash* для операционной системы *gnu*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), которую чаще всего и можно встретить, максимальное целое равно 2 в 63-й степени минус 1:

```
$ ((x=2**63-1)); echo $x
9223372036854775807
```

если к этому числу добавить единицу, то, из-за арифметического переполнения, получим отрицательное число:

```
$ ((x=2**63-1)); echo $((x+1))
-9223372036854775808
```

---

по поводу же сравнения: если в выражении (аналог приведённому вашему)

```
$ test $x -le $amount
```

в переменной `$amount` будет строка, которую *bash* не сможет преобразовать в целое (например, 2 в 63-й степени), то при выполнении получим ошибку:

```
$ test $x -le 9223372036854775808
bash: test: 9223372036854775808: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score -1):

Целочисленный - 32 бита в командной строке.
Выкинет сообщение, что Вы ввели большее число, чем заложено в типе переменной а. Еще до компилирования программы.

Comment: Компилирования? А там разве не интерпретирование?